# How do I keep a dialog box always on top?

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog

I created a dialog box like this:

```
String response = 
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"message","title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I'd like to keep it always on top of all windows.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, using Java, having a system modal dialog is not possible. The best you can have is a toolkit modal option pane. That's to say an option pane that stay in front of all Java windows.

[This example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/dialog-modality.html) explains how Java6 allows you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get the question, but I quickly created desktop app with code you posted and it actually is modal ...

Comment: Modal to the application, not the system. He wants it modal on the system.